# Create space between an icon and text label in a button

Tags: css

Hi have buttons on my website that could have material icons inside (left or right). For example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  Button Label
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
  Button Label
  <span class="material-icons-outlined"> settings </span>
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <span class="material-icons-outlined"> settings </span>
  Button Label
</button>
```

As you can see, icon could be present or not and in case is present, it could be before or after text.

I'd need to "space" this icon from text, but I can't simply apply `margin:0 20px` to it because I'd need to create space only between text and icon and from icon to button side.

I thought that a possible solution could be wrap text label in another `span` to target it and then use `:first-child` or `:last-child` to target icon but... if could be possible to not add this wrap could be ideal.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  <span>Button Label</span>
  <span class="material-icons-outlined"> settings </span>
</button>

.material-icons-outlined:last-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You can use `flexbox`'s `gap` property here.

Comment: uhuuu it seems the solution and... also support is nice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving text an id and icon an id, then providing a margin? Just a thought. I believe you can also wrap it as you mentioned. Flexbox might be worth a go as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It should be like wrapping elements. The key is that wrap text is completely unuseful when icon is missing.. I'd prefer, if possible, to simply add icon when needed and not modify also text label, wrapping it, when add an icon, or converserly always wrap text also when not needed